# How can I reset tick mark labels on an image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab

I want to know how to reset tick mark labels on an image in MATLAB. You can find my code below. The image seems to come with axes that already have their own tick marks. I want to rescale the axes such the both the x and y axes go from 0 to 100. Any suggestions would be fantastic.

```
% Code
img = imread('IMG.JPG'); 
imagesc(img);
axis equal;
```

Comment: You want to crop to the interval [0, 100], or you want to reassign the axes so the the edges are 0 and 100?  And will any other plots be sharing the same `axes` object, or is changing the tick labels enough?

Comment: I want to reassign the axes so the edges are 0 to 100. And changing the tick labels is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the coordinate frame of the image as follows:

```
x = linspace(0, 100, size(img, 2));
y = linspace(0, 100, size(img, 1));
imagesc(x, y, img);
axis image
```

...which would answer your question about making x and y explicitly go from 0 to 100. But if the image already has tick marks in it and you want to hide matlab's ticks, just add `axis off` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that actually distorts the picture. The reason why I have the 'axis equal' command in my code is to avoid distorting the picture.

Answer (score 1):

To mark the axes as 0:100 regardless of the actual data scaling, you can do:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [0:10] * size(img,1)/10, 'XTickLabel', [0:10] * 10);
set(gca, 'YTick', [0:10] * size(img,2)/10, 'YTickLabel', [0:10] * 10);
```

Not tested; you might also need a `num2str` thrown in for the labels.